# Managing an Array of Likes in AngularJS Service

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a like Button on Profile Page, On click of Like Button i want to maintain an array of like and store it into my db.

in profile Controller I have

`$scope.likeProfile = UserService.likeProfile(loggedInUser,$state.params.userId);`

In User Service I have

```
function likeProfile(likedBy,id){
   var likeArray = [];
   likeArray.push(likedBy);
   ref.child("users").child(id).update({ likedBy: likeArray});
}
```

I just want to understand how I could not intialize likeArray everyTime LikeProfile Method is called. So that all likes are pushed into array.

Comment: Not clear about initializing since you are always creating  `var likeArray = [];` everytime likeProfile is called.

Comment: function doesn't return anything. Really not clear what objective is either. Someone with 12K rep should be able to put together more comprehensive problem and objective statements

Comment: Yes the question is dat only how i cannot var likeArray = [] use this line and the array keeps adding all the likes

Comment: just move out this line `var likeArray = []; function likeProfile(likedBy,id){`

Comment: @charlietfl IMHO it is not a good idea judging by rep

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak not judging at all... but anyone who has obviously seen many hundreds of questions knows how this site works and knows  good questions from poorly put together ones. The basics are pretty simple...a clear problem statement and objective which this one seems to lack both

Comment: @charlietfl  Not sure if i was not able to clear the Objective. The objective is to have a array that persist when different people like users profile. I am old to Stackoverflow but new to Angular and JS not sure if i want something like a global array.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this, not sure though if this is what you want to achieve. Initialization should not be done within the function if you want to keep the result. This keeps the result within the scope of *one user*.

```
$scope.likeArray = [];

function likeProfile (likedBy, id) {
    $scope.likeArray.push(likedBy);
    ref.child("users").child(id).update({ likedBy: likeArray});
}
```

*Otherwise*, if you need **overall likes** you have to initialize the array with the previous values *within* the function, sth. like

```
likeArray = getLikesFromDB();   // however you access your db
likeArray.push(likedBy);
ref.child("users").child(id).update({ likedBy: likeArray });
```

Try to debug with the browser dev tools (e.g. in Chrome Tools > Developer Tools) and see what you send in the network tab. If your array only contains one value the whole array will be overwritten unless you write a custom update function that adds a value rather than replaces the value.